# Drop input voltage for a boost converter

Tags: voltage, dc-dc-converter, buck, boost, converter

I have a 21V DC solar panel power source, that feeds a DC-DC boost converter. I set the output voltage of the boost converter to 19.5V to charge my laptop, but since the input voltage is higher than that, the output voltage is also 21V. I cannot use a buck converter, because when I draw current from the boost converter, input voltage drops below 19.5V, so it must be boosted to stay at 19.5V. How can I prevent the initial (when first plugged in) voltage to be below 19.5V?

**________________________**

On mains power, the laptop draws about 1.5A of current at 19.5V, and that is about 30W. My solar panel is 50W under direct full sunlight.

The PV panel's Voc is 21.46V, Isc is 3.21A,
Vmp is 17.46V, Imp is 2.98A.
Is does not have a part number.

Comment: You need a buck-boost converter.

Comment: I thought maybe a simple resistor or a zener diode connected in parallel with the input would do, am I correct? I just need to drop the input voltage about 4-5 volts for it to work safely.

Comment: Maybe.  We don't know how much max current you are drawing so the power loss in a resistor or zener could be large.  A resistor would give you a variable voltage drop with load, so the voltage could pop up and possibly damage your machine when it sleeps for example.  A zener (or more likely 2 diodes in series) could provide a constant drop, but then your output voltage will cut out from low input voltage that much sooner.  Of the two, the two (not Schottky) diodes in series would have the best chance of working.

Comment: What do you mean by "but then your output voltage will cut out from low input voltage that much sooner"?

Comment: Depending on how your boost converter works, the output voltage at some point when the panel is not in full sunlight could start to drop or the converter may shut down due to input undervoltage.  Since you're wasting some power in your diodes to drop the voltage on the output, that will happen sooner than it would otherwise.

Comment: Important: Q1 You say 21V. Is that measured open circuit in full sun or spec plate or ? Q2: Do you have specification, part number? web link? Q3: What is the panel rated power output? Q4: What is the laptop psu power spec  (V, I, Watts)? || || As Tony notes in his answer, a PV panel with Voc of 21V will typically have a full power voltage of 80%-85%  of that = here about 17 to 18 V. ie you panel IF 21 Voc has too low a voltage output to operate at 19V+.

Comment: ... You need a boost converter with Vmax set to 19.5V. Even that will not work if the panel cannot supply enough current / power for the power supply at 19.5V - some (many) supplies) will load the source until they reach some minimum power level.

Comment: You don't have to go so strict with a spec if you just want to charge your laptop. All laptops charge fine between 16 and 20 volts. Just because there is a buck converter inside that converts that voltage to battery voltage anyway (some 12V). And that buck converter of course can take a whole range of voltages as input, and if you deviate from 19.5 down to 18, or just go with Type-C 20V,you will be 100% equally fine.Take it into account when solving your problem and don't chase superstrict limitation, there is no practical point in it.Maybe 18V output will be easy to maintain, go with it then!

Comment: @Ilya Sadly, what you say is correct in dome but not in all cases. Some laptops have buck-boost internal circuitry and can accept a range of voltages. Others - and I have seen a number of these - will not accept less than a voltage quite close to the formal spec. For example, with a 4S LiIon battery, Vmax at battery = 4.2V x 4 = 16.8V. The charger needs some headroom so maybe 18V in some cases and maybe somewhat more for some. If the system CANNOT boost the input then it will not work if Vin is too low.  ...

Comment: ... On the other hand I have seen an HP laptop that had 3S and 4S battery packs available and it would happily charge either from a 19V adaptor - HP are masters of power management, unlike some. || Also, if a charger is loaded below its related voltage it may attempt to supply more than rated current - this may cause shutdown and may cause damage depending on design. If say an adaptor is rated at 19V 3A and is loaded to draw 5A it may drop to 16V. The laptop MAY reject the voltage, the psu may shut down, it may fail or it all may just work.

Comment: ...  In the case of a PV panel - if it works at lower voltage then no damage is likely BUT you will usually not get more than about an extra 5 to 10% under heavy load below specified voltage.

Comment: I took the risk and directly connected the solar panel output to the laptop power input. Nothing bad happened fortunately, but the laptop switches between plugged in state and on battery state, continuously. Does that indicate an insufficient current case? The solar panel is 50 Watts, seeing the sunlight directly, not behind a window or glass, and there is full sunlight now, with no clouds. On mains power, the laptop draws about 1.5A of current at 19.5V, and that is about 30W. My solar panel is 50W under direct full sunlight. I don't understand the problem now.

Comment: Maybe I should connect a 30W resistor with 13 ohms resistance to draw 1.5A from the solar panel, and see if it can supply this much current with a multimeter.

Comment: @EmreTapcı As noted above - if you answered my Q1 Q2 it would help us help you. I do not know if your 21V panel is really somewhat less but IF that's 21V O/C then you can expect about 17-18V so the panel may be loading down to under where the laptop works, stopping charging, going back to no load and recycling continually. What I aid above applies.

Comment: Its Voc is 21.46V,  Isc is 3.21A, Vpm is 17.46V, Ipm is 2.98A. Is does not have a part number.

Comment: @EmreTapcı Thanks.  You **MAY** be able to get this to work by adding a large capacitor across the panel output - but a boost converter with Vout ~=19V out is more likely to work. || Those figures match what I and Tony suggested reasonably well. Vmp/Voc = 81% and Isc/Imp= 8% more current. || The panel has enough current and power capability but probably not enough voltage capability. | IF you  have a suitable variable power supply avail;able you can find where the laptop's cutout point is - supply 19V at enough amps and then reduce Vpsu until the laptop stops charging.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I do not have a variable power supply. I ordered a charge controller and a battery to use with the solar panel. The battery will act as a buffer, like the capacitor that you suggested.

Comment: @EmreTapcı The charge controller may prevent the voltage rising too high but unless it contains a boost converter (possibly in the form of an MPPT controller) it will be unlikely top help you. || Do you have controller and battery specs and/or web links? | The battery spec is crucial unless the controller is specifically intended to deal with it. It is likely adding a battery will be wasted. More information will help us help you. || A large capacitor MAY be more useful than a battery (except with MPPT   as the cap will allow operation at the highest possible voltage under a given 
 load.

Answer (score 2):

**No this will never work well.**

A Solar Panel is an optical-powered current-source that starts at a high impedance with no power. It has an open-circuit voltage, Voc and a short circuit current, Isc. In order to capture **maximum power,** there is a law that states the source & load impedances must be matched.  There are many algorithms to maximize this power transfer or [MPPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_point_tracking), e.g. hunting, and setting the approximate voltage based on a solar input sensor etc.

At max. solar input the Vmax is ~ 82% for Pmax out. This also defines the MPPT impedance R = V/I characteristic of the active source to the load.

However, a mobile smart battery charger expects a constant voltage and draws current according to its State of Charge (SoC). e.g. 19.5V +/-10%. Usually starting at constant current, CC then CV then cutoff at 10 to 5% of CC.

So you need to regulate both the MPT impedance to get maximum power and supply a fixed voltage within a reasonable range of 19.5V. This DCDC smart charger will have its own battery charger and step down regulators for logic and analog voltages simultaneously so it does not have to be exact, yet to get max power from the panel, it does need to be more precise..

You can choose an MPPT dual regulator for your battery and Solar Panel chemistry or something that matches the V/I characteristic your Solar Panel and conditions and charger voltage range of say 10%.

The panel needs to have Voc=24V to make a simple efficient regulator and have enough power to start the mobile charger so it must be sized greater than your maximum charger power rating to get started.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you plug in your laptop and it starts charging, the voltage will drop down to 19.5V and everything will be okay. There's also a decent chance that 21V is within tolerance for your laptop anyway and it won't be harmed. But, just to remove the risk, you want to make sure it never ever goes higher than 19.5V. Fair enough.

You don't want to drop the input voltage when it's below 19.5V, because then you're needlessly wasting power.

With that in mind, I suggest that you can connect a *shunt regulator* to the input. A shunt regulator is a device which, when the voltage is too high, draws current to bring the voltage back down. When the voltage is low enough, it doesn't do anything.

The simplest type of shunt regulator is a Zener diode, but remember this has to absorb some of the power from the solar panel when the laptop isn't plugged in, and I don't think they make 50-watt Zener diodes.

The basic design is to put a transistor in parallel with the input, and then adjust the transistor's base current (or gate voltage) until it's dissipating enough power to bring the voltage down to where you want it - something you can do with an op-amp. Putting an extra resistor in series will shift some of the power dissipation to the resistor, which might be more tolerant of high temperatures. Here's a **rough draft**:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBFDrQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

OA1 adjusts the current through R1 and M1 (for some reason I couldn't rename it to Q1) until the + input voltage (1/3 of the supply voltage) matches the Zener voltage (1/3 of 19.5V). Both R1 and M1 will need heatsinks.

Comment: Sadly, it seems that while the PV panel Voc is above spec, the Vmp is probably BELOW the laptop charging voltage and the system tends to cycle in and out of charge .